# Array stacking over another array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to add an item to an array, but the arrays keep stacking over one another and it becomes unusable.

I have tried different methods and I can make it work if my input doesn't come from `get_user_meta()` and instead I create a custom string to test the array. But I need to load the meta so I can just add additional content into it.

```php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$the_id = get_the_ID();
$continue_watching = get_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',false);
if ( !isset($continue_watching) ) {
     $continue_watching = array();
}
$continue_watching[] = $the_id;
update_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',$continue_watching);
```

This is what is happening:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16966
                    [1] => 16966
                )

            [1] => 11234
        )

    [1] => 16951
)
```

But I expected the output to look like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 11234
    [1] => 16951
    [2] => 16966
    [3] => 16970
)
```

Update:

I have reset the array and this is the output just after `$continue_watching = get_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',false);`

```
    Array
(
)
```

This is the output after `$continue_watching[] = $the_id;`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16955
)
```

After opening another page, this is the output after `$continue_watching = get_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',false);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16955
        )

)
```

And this is the output after `$continue_watching[] = $the_id;`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16955
        )

    [1] => 16957
)
```

Comment: Well, without showing us that function `update_user_meta()` there is hardly anything we can say here...

Comment: Post output of `print_r($continue_watching)`immediately after `$continue_watching = get_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',false);`

Comment: I have updated it with the recommendation proposed to help debug. Do you have any idea of what I could be doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the alternatives, it turned out to be a very simple solution. All I had to do was change the value from false to true inside the wordpress function `get_user_meta($user_id,'continue_watching',false);`

The "false" option was displaying the array inside another array, when I changed it to "true" the output was the array contained inside the variable alone.